# Remove ending trailing slash from .htaccess configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess

I Created a directory with name `test.example.com` which has `index.html` in directory `test.example.com`

> I have the following path on the domain:

`http://example.com/test.example.com/`

and .htaccess with following configuration

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

upon visiting `http://example.com/test.example.com/` i would like to redirect on removed trailing slash `http://example.com/test.example.com` hosted with index.html

Comment: `test.example.com` is a real directory and it's not a good idea to remove trailing slash after directories for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need an external redirection removing a potential trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(test\.example\.com)/$ /$1 [R=301]
```

In case you also want to apply that rule to paths below that folder this will do:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(test\.example\.com)(.*)/$ /$1$2 [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).